# How to improve accuracy of all the labels ? What are the possible ways to achieve more accurate results for all the classes?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, optimization, deep-learning

I am working on an image classification problem. Doing it by my own model (Using CNN) and It's 4-class problem. I have used approximately equal number of images for each label to train the model.

The problem is predictions are very good accurate other than class-3 images. Not doing good for class-3 frames.

So, What steps can lead to improving predictions of class-3 without affecting the predictions of remaining classes.

Comment: We are not wizards. We know nothing about your problem and how you addressed it. So my best advice is "try again".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Answer (score 0):

retrain your model with larger number of class-3 frames.